# Rails UJS - Unbind Event handlers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've a delete button generated by the `link_to` helper method. It produces the following markup.

```
<a href="/clips/150" class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a>
```

When, I click this button, it opens `confirm` dialog box as expected.

However, I want to override this confirm dialog box. I want to show a confirm dialog box using [Bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com).

So, I tried to unbind the click events from these buttons.  I've tried all the following ways (in console). But none works.

```
$('a[data-confirm]').unbind('click')
```

or,

```
$('a[data-confirm]').off('click')
```

or,

```
$('a[data-confirm]').undelegate('click')
```

Even, I tried `click.rails` as event name as I see this is the declaration in jquery_ujs.js.

```
$(document).delegate(rails.linkClickSelector, 'click.rails', function(e) {
```

You may ask me to remove `:confirm => true` when calling helper method. But I don't want that. I want that as default feature. I will override runtime. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

How about overriding the default confirm action? See source code of UJS:

```
// Default confirm dialog, may be overridden with custom confirm dialog in $.rails.confirm
confirm: function(message) {
  return confirm(message);
},
```

Comment: you took me to right path. I could just override `$.rails.confirm`.

Answer (score 1):

Though I asked how to override the rails ujs default confirm method, my actual intention was to use the bootbox confirm dialog instead of default browser's confirm box.

I got out of the box solution here. I'm linking this here so that it helps someone else with similar requirements:

https://gist.github.com/2823526